# Display request method (GET,POST, ..) in Laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I have a middleware class in Laravel and I wanted to get the action name like (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT,...) for logging the information. I have below code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $api_key = $request->headers->get('x-api-key');
    if($api_key!=$this->auth_key){
        return $this->response->unauthorize(
            "You're not authorize to access. Make sure that you're passing your api Key"
        );
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

I have this line `$request->route()`; that may help but I don't know about the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

private $route;

public __construct(Route $route) {
  $this->route = $route;
}

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $action = $this->route->getMethods(); // return array

    $api_key = $request->headers->get('x-api-key');
    if($api_key!=$this->auth_key){
        return $this->response->unauthorize(
            "You're not authorize to access. Make sure that you're passing your api Key"
        );
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: `App\Http\Controllers\LookupController@show_all` this will return this not the request method if you see my question the request method like `GET, POST, PUT`.... etc.

Comment: Also `public function handle($request, Closure $next, Route $route)` this is wrong. `handle` function can't take 3 parameters. So you should create a constructor and put the `Route $route` in that and then you are able to access.

Comment: not working getmethods in laravel 9